# How can I expand the range of my whistle register?

Tags: technique, vocal-range

My current highest whistle note is B6 but I want to expand it to D7 or E7. Any tips on how to do that safely? Thank you!

(p.s., I can't see a vocal coach because I have social anxiety.)

Comment: Can you provide us with an audio sample so I can judge your technique? This is very important for me to be able to guide you any further.

Comment: Honestly, you should see a voice coach... otherwise, you are stuck with searching for advice online only. There is generally only very basic or extremely advanced advice in such cases; rarely is there much for intermediates. Finally, since this sort of thing varies from person to person and also requires proper mouth and body positioning, you should provide both video and audio to be reviewed in order to give you any adequate advice.